# How to synchronize multiple appsinks

Tags: c, parallel-processing, synchronization, gstreamer

I've been learning gstreamer, trying to write an app which takes multiple video files and synchronously processes each frame from them (Specifically I need to compare those frames until turning to next ones). 
I've built a pipeline which has several, independent 'branches':

```
filesrc ---> decodebin ---> videoconvert ---> appsink

filesrc ---> decodebin ---> videoconvert ---> appsink

...

filesrc ---> decodebin ---> videoconvert ---> appsink
```

I've managed to process frames independently of each other.
My question is:

**how can I synchronize each appsink so that i could compare frames from one appsink with frames from the others?**

All that comes into my mind is to poll in new-sample callback function whether other appsinks have stored their buffers in some shared memory and afterwards one of these callbacks gets to do work on all buffers. However this seems to be quite brutal and messy approach. Could you help me find a better one?

Answer (score 0):

All sinks (inheriting from GstBaseSink) in GStreamer have a property "sync". This means it is going to sync the buffer-timestamp to the clock-time, and not give you the buffer until its time is up. If you have this enabled, you can simply use the GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP on the buffer to compare them.